# Vba code to Index if Cell contains string

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with **Vba** code for running Index on Cell `G3`, `H3` and `I3` if cell `E3` doesn't contain a "Word".

If the cell `E3` contains a "Word" the cell `G3`, `H3` and `I3` should be cleared of formulas and open for user input.

I wish to protect the sheet so not sure if the above approach will work.

Another option could be as below.

If the Cell `E3` contains a "Word" then user gets a message box to enter the values for cells `G3`, `H3` and `I3` or else `G3`,`H3` and `I3` run the index formula.

Comment: What code, and code attempt, do you have so far? 
Protection is not necessarily an issue as you could unprotect, modify, and protect the sheet if necessary.

Comment: Hi Andy, I am a noob for VBA so no attempt, tried several workarounds using Non-Vba but couldn't get it done.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will check if the contents of E3 have changed and if so, it will check if the cell contains the text "Word" (not case sensitive), if it does contain the text, it will clear cells G3, H3 & I3.

Place the code under the sheet you are working with, using the `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$E$3" Then 'check if the value in cell E3 has changed
        If InStr(UCase(Target), "WORD") > 0 Then
        'check if the text "Word" (not case sensitive) is within the contents of the cell
            Range("G3:I3").ClearContents 'if yes then clear G3:I3
            MsgBox "Please fill the cells G3, H3 & I3", vbInformation, "Populate"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Further to your comments I've now updated my answer, the code below will lock all the cells in your worksheet apart from Column E, once a cell in Column E has been populated, it will unlock the columns in that row for G,H and I, so the user can input the necessary data:

```
Sub LockCells()
'lock all cells apart from Column E
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("E:E").Locked = False 'leave unlocked
ws.Range("G:I").Locked = True 'lock these columns
ws.Protect Password:="xx", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
'change the password to whatever you wish
End Sub

Sub UnlockWorksheet()
'You might need this to unlock the sheet
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Unprotect Password:="xx"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If Target.Column = 5 Then 'check if the value in Column E has changed
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            ws.Range("G" & Target.Row & ":I" & Target.Row).Locked = False
        'check if the text "Word" (not case sensitive) is within the contents of the cell
            ws.Range("G" & Target.Row & ":I" & Target.Row).ClearContents  'if yes then clear G:I
            MsgBox "Please fill the columns G, H & I", vbInformation, "Populate"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Xabier, Thanks for the help. But for some reason, the code didn't work. Here is the actual scenario on which I am trying to implement. Column E is labelled Package Vendor, and has a Dropdown list of n Vendors. Column F is Labelled Package Code and has a dependent list of Packaging Code from n Vendors in Column E. Column G,H,I are L/W/H (Length/Width/Height). User selects the Vendor then Package code and the sheet gives the L/W/H in Column G/H/I. I want that Column G/H/I be locked and no editable until user selects "Your Packaging" in Column E, so that user can input L/W/H manually.

Comment: This is needed for all cells in Column E and reflective cells in Column G/H/I

Comment: @UtkarshSingh I've now updated my answer to reflect your comments, hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried the code and it does work but partially. The whole lock and unlock section didn't seem to work. Let me clarify further, the worksheet is locked for users and they are not allowed to unlock it. The code must work in the background without letting the worksheet unlocked. (Not sure if possible). Columns G,H,I have Index formulas so if the user selects "Word" in Column E and contents are deleted the formula should come back if the user selects any other option than "Word" in Column E. I am not sure if sharing the sheet to you will be mor helpful.

Comment: @UtkarshSingh please do share your spreadsheet as the code I've added locked the interface but not VBA, so unless I can see what your spreadsheet is actually doing I would be guessing and wasting your and my time...